# c# wpf Window.Visibility doesn't always update grafic view

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application with WPF that is using multiple threads. Sometimes when I try to close a window it won’t close but it seems that the application thinks that it is closed since the application works as if the window is closed. The only way to close the window is to restart the application. This error does not occur often and is very hard to reproduce.

I have three visibility properties, Main, Second and Third. The properties determines what view are to be shown. I have a problem with the second property.

When a Window is opened a corresponding view is set to that property and the view is visible.

When a window is closed a cancel event is sent that changes the property back to main.

However in the second property the cancel event don't have to be sent. If I open a new window the property is changed to that and the old window is hidden.

```
//This is in MySecondWindowView
<Window.Visibility> 
    <Binding Path="SecondInput"
            Source="{x:Static MyApplication:MainViewModel.Instance}"
            Converter="{StaticRecource InputVisibilityConverter}"
            ConverterParameter="MySecondWindow">
    </Binding>
</Window.Visibility>

//Method is in SomeViewModel
private void ExecuteShowMySecondWondowCommand()
{
    try
    {
        MainViewModel.Instance.MySecondWondowVM.FilePath = FilePath;
    }
    Catch(ArgumentException e)
    {
        "Error Message"
    }
    MainViewModel.Instance.SecondInput = InputTypeEnum.MySecondWindow;
}

//Method is in MySecondWindowViewModel
private void ExecuteCancelCommand()
{
    MainViewModel.Instance.SecondInput = InputTypeEnum.Main;
}
```

Can this be a threading issue since the error is so rare or am i doing anything else wong?

Comment: Is your property implementing INofityPropertyChanged interface.? (Are u notifying the ui of the change in bool value)

Comment: yes it is. Most of the time there is no error. Sometimes it happens and I have to restart the application.

Comment: set a two-way binding